Trouble calculating an integral in the complex plane
The integral in question is $$2 \int_0^{+\infty}z^{2b-1}  sinz \cdot dz \quad \quad b>0$$
I have tried 2 different but similar approaches, one calculating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}z^{2b-1}  e^{iz} \cdot dz$ and then take the imaginary part, but using Jordan's lemma and since the integral has no poles, it vanishes!
My second approach uses the fact that $sinz = \dfrac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}$. I use that identity to break the integral in 2 parts and once again integrate in closed contours and use Jordan's lemma. I get $$ \int_0^{+\infty}z^{2b-1}  e^{iz} \cdot dz = \int_0^{+\infty}z^{2b-1}  e^{-iz} \cdot dz = (-1)^{b-1} \Gamma(2b-1)$$ But, since I want to subtract one integral from the other, the final result once again vanishes! I am sure the result cannot be zero, and I know it must contain Gamma functions, but I cannot figure out my mistake

You are presumably considering the case $-1 < 2b-1 < 0$. As, if $2b-1 > 1$ you wouldn't have $\lim_{|z| \rightarrow \infty} z^{2b-1} =0$ and you wouldn't be able to apply Jordan's lemma. Are you assuming that $z^{2b-1} \sin z$ is an even function in order to extend the range of integration so that you are integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$? This would be incorrect: $\int_{-\infty}^0 x^{2b-1} e^{ix} dx = \int_0^\infty (-x)^{2b-1} e^{-ix} dx =e^{i \pi (2b-1)} \int_0^\infty x^{2b-1} e^{-ix} dx = (\cos \pi (2b-1) + i \sin \pi (2b-1)) \int_0^\infty x^{2b-1} e^{-ix} dx$.

I meant to say "As, if $2b−1>0$ you wouldn't have $\lim_{|z| \rightarrow \infty} z^{2b−1}=0$ and you wouldn't be able to apply Jordan's lemma."

You are right, I overlooked that part. Now I really have an issue on how to calculate the integral

Have you tried integrating $\oint_C z^{2b-1} e^{iz} dz$ along the contour from $0$ to $R$ along the positive real axis, then along the arc from $R$ to $iR$, and then from $iR$ to $0$? Then take the limit $R \rightarrow \infty$? The integral along the arc vanishes in this limit because you have $e^{-R \sin \theta}$ involved. You then take the imaginary part at the end. A quick calculation gives me $\int_0^\infty x^{2b-1} \sin x dx = \sin \frac{\pi}{2} (2b-1) \Gamma(2b+1)$. I may write it up later when I'm less busy, unless you do the calculation yourself.

Sorry I meant to write this: $\int_0^\infty x^{2b-1} \sin x dx = \sin (b \pi) \Gamma (2b)$.

Thanks a ton, I think this is the right answer!

Consider the function $\displaystyle f(z) = z^{\alpha-1}e^{-cz}, c>0$
You need a very special kind of contour for that kind of integrals. It is a semi-annulus, something similar to this:
$$\gamma_1(t) = t, \quad t\in (\epsilon, R)$$
$$\gamma_2(\theta) = Re^{i\theta}, \;\theta\in(0,\beta), \;-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \beta \leq\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$ \gamma_3(t) = -te^{i\beta} \quad t\in(-R,-\epsilon)$$
$$\gamma_4(\theta) = \epsilon e^{-i\theta}, \; \theta\in(-\beta,0)$$
Note that the function $f(z)$ has a branch point at $z=0$ which is not inside the contour. Additionally, if we take the branch cut $(-\infty,0)$ for the principal branch of $z^{\alpha-1}$ the function $f(z)$ is analytic in the contour.
Hence, by the residue theorem:
$$\oint_{\gamma=\gamma_1+...\gamma_4} f(z) dz = \int_{\epsilon}^{R}t^{\alpha-1}e^{-ct}dt+ iR\int_{0}^{\beta}R^{\alpha-1}e^{(\alpha-1)i\theta}e^{-cRe^{i\theta}}d\theta-e^{i\beta}\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}(-t)^{\alpha-1}e^{(\alpha-1)i\beta}e^{cte^{i\beta}} dt -i\epsilon \int_{-\beta}^{0}\epsilon^{\alpha-1}e^{-(\alpha-1)i\theta}e^{-c\epsilon e^{-i\theta}}d\theta = 0$$
If $\epsilon \to 0$ and $R \to \infty$:
$$ iR\int_{0}^{\beta}R^{\alpha-1}e^{(\alpha-1)i\theta}e^{-cRe^{i\theta}}d\theta \to 0$$
$$ -i\epsilon\int_{-\beta}^{0}\epsilon^{\alpha-1}e^{-(\alpha-1)i\theta}e^{-c\epsilon e^{-i\theta}}d\theta \to 0$$
Threfore
$$ \int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}(-t)^{\alpha-1}e^{\alpha i\beta}e^{cte^{i\beta}} dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\alpha-1}e^{-ct}dt $$
Or what is the same
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\alpha-1}e^{-ct\cos(\beta)-ict\sin(\beta)} dt = \Gamma(\alpha)c^{-\alpha}e^{-i\alpha\beta}$$
If $\displaystyle \beta = \frac{\pi}{2}$
$$ -i\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\alpha-1}\sin(ct) dt = \Gamma(\alpha)c^{-\alpha}e^{-i\alpha\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
Taking imaginary part in both sides:
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\alpha-1}\sin(ct) dt = \Gamma(\alpha)c^{-\alpha}\sin\left(\frac{\alpha \pi}{2}\right)$$
If $c=1, \alpha=2b$
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{2b-1}\sin(t) dt = \Gamma(2b)\sin\left(b\pi\right)$$
